# How is a Stack the generalisation of a sheaf from a 2-category point of view?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, soft-question, sheaf-theory, stacks

A stack is usually given in terms of:

-A category $F$ fibered over another $C$ such that the functor $Hom(x,y), x,y \in F(\alpha), \alpha \in C$ is a sheaf

-The descent data are effective.

There is an equivalent [definition](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/stack), using the Grothendieck construction, which is a correspondence between fibered categories and pseudofunctors in $Cat$. Given this correspondence a stack becomes a (contravariant) pseudofunctor such that descent is effective.

Now, with this definition in mind it seems obvious that a stack is a generalised sheaf. But here is my doubt:

When defining a sheaf $T$ over a space $X$, is not unusual to see the following diagram (naively)

$ T(X) \rightarrow T(U) \stackrel{\longrightarrow}{\longrightarrow} T(U \cap U)$

While, saying that descent data are effective is like asking a similar diagram, but there is the difference that here descent satisfies cocycle condition, something which is naively in $U \cap U \cap U$.

Recalling that (for example) locally constant sheaves automatically satisfy the cocycle condition because of their correspondent covering spaces do.

So my question is, at the light of my interpretation, the cocycle condition seems to me the only obstruction to the fact that a stack is a generalised sheaf. Am i wrong? Every sheaf trivially satisfies cocycle condition?

Comment: Strictly speaking, this depends on how do you realize presheaves as particular prestacks. Since your context is 2-categorical, your definitions must be equivalence-invariant. One such invariant way is to consider presheaves as prestacks valued in categories that are *equivalent* to discrete categories (sometimes called setoids). In this context then, the cocycle condition is not entirely trivial. It is related to things like [local equivalence relations](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166864195001018), foliations, etc.

Comment: This diagram is not naive. It's actually correct once you use homotopy colimits and add all the intersections (not only the double intersections). In other words, in a sheaf you require that sections coinciding in a intersection must glue to a global section, while in a stack, sections connected by an arrow in each double intersection (that is coherent with other arrows) must glue to a global section. More generally, you could relax these commutative triangles to be only commutative up to a 2-morphism with coherences between these 2-morphisms and so on (this would be an $\infty$-stack)

Comment: Oh ok, maybe i see what is the problem. Usually (see Vistoli's notes) a descent data is given by sections, and arrows between section in the double intersection (isomorphism) such that on triple intersections they satisfy cocycle condition with equality$\phi_{ij}\phi_{jk}=\phi_{ik}$. But in a 2-categorical environment we have that this equality will be a 2-isomorphism with compatibility in quadruple intersections (what a pseudofunctor guarantee). Is this the point?

Comment: If I understand correctly the comment by @user40276, it is about maximally general formulation: sheaf/stack/... condition is that certain kind of colimits are carried to the same kind of limits. In every case, coproducts must go to products; the rest is about some kind of coequalizers go to the same kind of equalizers. For sheaves it is that if $U\times_XU\rightrightarrows U\to X$ is a coequalizer then $F(X)\to F(U)\rightrightarrows F(U\times_XU)$ must be an equalizer. Higher and higher, you get $n$-truncated simplicial objects, which, if exact, must go to exact $n$-truncated cosimplicials,...

Comment: (where exact truncated simplicial, resp. cosimplicial object means that $X$, resp. $F(X)$, is the homotopy colimit, resp. homotopy limit, of this truncated simplicial, resp. cosimplicial object considered as a diagram)

Comment: I don't know if I've understood your reply. In a sheaf $F: O(X) \rightarrow Set$, for $s_i \in F (U_i)$, we have that the descent data $s_i|_{U_{ij}} = s_j|_{U_{ij}}$ for every $I$ and $j$ is equivalent to the data $s \in F(X)$. Now if we want a 1-categorial version of this for $F: O(X) \rightarrow Grp$, we can define analogously that a descent data $\phi_{ji} : s_i|_{U_{ij}} \rightarrow s_{j}|_{U_{ij}}$ such that $\phi_{ij}\phi_{jk} = \phi_{ik}$ on $F(U_{ijk})$ is equivalent to a global section. .....

Comment: Now for the 2-categorial case for $F: O(X) \rightarrow 2-Grpd$, a descent data will be the same thing as a descent data for the 1-categorial case except that we will have a 2-morphism $\lambda_{ijk}: \phi_{ij} \phi_{jk} \rightarrow \phi_{ik}$ instead of equality and this 2-morphism must satisfy a commutative diagram for each $i, j$ and $k$. This diagram will be a polyhedra with faces indexed by each $\lambda_{lmn}$ and edges given by the triangles with faces $\phi_{wv}$.....

Comment: Now for the higher categorial case for $F: O(X) \rightarrow \infty-Grpd$, we require this big polyhedra to be commutative up to a 3-morphism and that these 3-morphisms must satisfy compatibilities (now a 4-dimensional polyhedra) up to 4-morphisms. This data of compatibilities can be packed up into a homotopy colimit. More precisely the groupoid $U \times_X U \xrightarrow{\rightarrow} U$ for $U = \coprod_{I} U_i$ can be extended to an $\infty$-groupoid $U$ such that $U_n = U \times_X ... \times_X U$ (n times) and a descent data will be the same thing as a section of $holim F(U_n)$. ...

Comment: For the $n$-categorial case you can truncate this $\infty$-groupoid to an n-groupoid and you will get the same result up to homotopy. Furthermore, as it was already noticed in the comments, this is equivalent to the preservation of a homotopy limit. This process of requiring things to be isomorphic instead of equal is the usual procedure for vertical categorification. However when requiring things to be isomorphic, you must require these isomorphisms to be compatible and so on.

Comment: And it should be $O(X)^{op}$ instead of $O(X)$. I cannot correct it anymore.

Comment: Don't you think those four comments constitute an answer, @user40276?

Comment: @user40276 Yes, my reply was (more naively, without the $\infty$ case) this. Thank you

Comment: @Ben Not exactly. I've written this in a rush. Maybe later when I have time, I may try to make an answer containing all the details. I hate incomplete answers. And I'm a little against the reputation point system of mathoverflow, so I usually avoid answering. Furthermore, I don't know how to draw diagrams properly here.

Comment: @HaroldF Ah! Ok. But there are no problems with Vistoli's presentation. Most of the cases that deals with moduli do not require 2-stacks (or 3-sheaves). Ah! And I forgot to write this. That cocycle condition guarantees that every possible way of restricting a local section gives you the same result. It's analogous to that theorem of Maclane which says that when the Maclane pentagon commutes then all the possible ways of associating an n-ary monoidal product gives you isomorphic objects.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let us start with what we know about sheaves, i.e. the "1-level". A sheaf  on a (Grothendieck) site $\mathcal{C}$ is a contravariant functor $F : \mathcal{C}^\text{op} \to \textbf{Set}$ such that for any cover $\{ X\ \to Y\}$ , the diagram
$$F(Y) \to F(X) \stackrel{\longrightarrow}{\longrightarrow} F (X \times_Y X)$$
is an equalizer in the category of sets. For the sake of exposition, I will only consider the case where the cover consists of a single element.

Now suppose we want to move to the "2-level" and talk about stacks. Then we need to throw in the cocycle condition, so we can **naively define** a stack $F$ to be a contravariant functor $\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}} \to \textbf{Set}$ such that

$$F(Y) \to F(X) \stackrel{\longrightarrow}{\longrightarrow} F (X \times_Y X)\stackrel{\stackrel{\longrightarrow}{\longrightarrow}}{\longrightarrow}  F(X \times_Y X \times_Y X)$$

is an equalizer in the category of sets. The problem now is the following:

> > If $F$ is some kind of moduli stack, e.g. $F = \mathcal{M}_{1,1}$ then to make $F$ set valued often involves quotiening out isomorphisms. However, this is very bad as the presence of quadratic twists of elliptic curves means $F$ is not injective.

So now what do we do? Well, we can try to not quotient out isomorphisms, and think of $F$ as a **groupoid** valued functor. But now we have a new problem:

> > If $F$ is valued in groupoids, what does it mean to say that $F(Y) \to F(X)$ is "injective"?

The solution is the following. Let's go back to situation where $F$ is a plain old sheaf, and let us think of the set $F(X)$ as a category where the only arrow $x \to x'$ is when $x = x'$, otherwise $\operatorname{Hom}(x,x') = \emptyset$. Then now to say that $F(Y) \to F(X)$ is injective is **exactly equivalent** to the statement that the functor   $F(Y) \to F(X)$ is **fully faithful**.

The upshot is that to make the right definition (of a prestack), we now know that:

1. $F(X)$ should be a groupoid.
2. $F(Y) \to F(X)$ should be fully faithful.

We're not there yet, and we need one last modification (at least for $F$ to be a prestack. We need to replace $F(X)$ with $F(X \to Y)$, namely the **category of covering data**. The objects of this category are pairs $(y, \phi)$ where $y \in F(Y)$ and $\phi : \text{pr}_1^\ast y \to \text{pr}_2^\ast y$ is an isomorphism. A morphism of covering data $ (y, \phi) \to (y', \phi')$ is a map $f : y\to y'$ such that an appropriate diagram commutes (see chapter 8 of the book "Neron Models" by BLR for the exact definition). We can now define:

> > A groupoid valued functor $F$ (or pseudofunctor in Vistoli's language) is a **prestack** if the natural pullback functor $F(Y) \to F(X \to Y)$ is fully faithful.

If you unravel what the morphisms are in the category $F(X \to Y)$, you will see this is exactly the condition that the **set-valued** functor $\underline{\operatorname{Isom}}$ is a plain old sheaf!

So we can finally get to your question. In my view, a stack **is** a generalized sheaf if you replace sets with groupoids, and if you introduce the category of covering data.